# Extract XML attribute with property

Tags: javascript, xml

The following XML object:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/user/christiaan123/topalbums.xml

Returns album covers under the 'image' attribute, but there are properties of 'size'. How can I return the url of `<image size="extralarge>` using javascript?

So far I've tried:

```
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

 xhttp.open("GET","http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/user/christiaan123/topalbums.xml",false);

 xhttp.send();
 lastFmData=xhttp.responseXML;

 albums = lastFmData.getElementsByTagName("album")
```

Comment: That returns a large number of albums. Precisely what image URL do you wish to obtain? Just the first one? All of them? Some other combination of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

 xhttp.open("GET","http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/user/christiaan123/topalbums.xml",false);

 xhttp.send();
 lastFmData=xhttp.responseXML;

 albums = lastFmData.getElementsByTagName("album")

 cover = []
 url = []
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
 console.log(divs);

 for (i=0; i<50; i++) {
    cover[i] = albums[i].children[8].innerHTML;
    url[i] = albums[i].children[3].innerHTML;
    divs[i].src = cover[i];
 }
```